# OpenGrok results not showing the matched lines contents

Tags: apache, tomcat, indexing, opengrok

I have configured the Opengrok 0.12.1 version with Tomcat 7.0, indexing is done successfully using the below command.

```
java -jar opengrok.jar -a on -C -W C:\opengrok-0.12.1\configuration.xml -c c:\ctags58\ctags.exe -P -S -v -s C:\ChangeDetails -d c:\opengrok-0.12.1\grokdata -Q on
```

But after that when I search for the results, it just showing the filenames where text is matched, but not showing the matched lines.

[image: OpenGrok Results sample]

Please let me know what changes needs to be done to show the matched lines as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the file content is in ASCII, thats when it will index and shows the result with line numbers. Else it will ignore and never shows the line number along with the results.